# C#, ASP.NET, MVC, Kendo UI Multiselect

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have written code for select all check-box to select all items, I am trying to write function when i uncheck the checkbox it should unselect all items.

Comment: Welcome to stack. I assume the question is about kendo grid but sharing some code can help get better and farter answers. Take the StackOverflow tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code, I can't really tailor my response to it, however, I have a simple solution.

In the select all checkbox change event, set the checked value of each of your checkboxes to equal the checked value of the select all check box.